# Avoid performance drawbacks with binary_ai and linguistic search / comp

Tags: oracle, performance

We're running an application where each database connection is opened with `nls_sort=binary_ai` and `nls_comp=linguistic`. As we have found out, this leads to massive performance drawbacks as opposed to setting both options to `binary`.

This leads to the following questions:

1. Does it matter what those settings were when creating indexes? What happens if you create the indexes while having set the connection settings to `binary` and switching to `binary_ai` and `linguistic` afterwards?

   I was unable to verify this on my own as it seems quite random to me whether oracle takes an index into account.
2. If the answer to 1 is "yes, it does matter", is there a way to re-create all the indexes automatically?
3. Do you have to create indexes in a special way (other than e.g. `create index idx_name on table_name("column_name");` for these settings to be performant?
4. Are there any other suggestions for getting queries to work faster with these two settings turned on?

Comment: Does "linguistic" even make sense together with "binary"? That's intended to deal with language specific rules, e.g. `'ss'` is considered the same as `'ß'` in German. I doubt this is the case in other languages. So what rules are applied without a language?

Comment: Very good question. We have columns in various languages. What would be the correct setting for a language-independent best-effort scenario?